# JMeter: How to deal with implicit result in Oracle 12C? ORA-20999: Oracle ERROR:: ORA-29478: Implicit result cannot be returned through this statement

Tags: oracle, jmeter

When calling a stored procedure through JMeter in an Oracle database, I get the following error:
`ORA-20999: Oracle ERROR:: ORA-29478: Implicit result cannot be returned through this statement`

I don't have 10 reputation so I cannot post images. I'll describe the configuration.

**This is my JDBC Connection information:**

```
Max Number of Connections:0  
Max Wait (ms):10000  
Time Between Eviction Runs (ms): 60000  
Auto Commit: True  
Transaction Isolation:TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED  
Test While Idle: True  
Soft Min Evictable Idle Time (ms): 5000  
Validation Query: select 1 from dual  
JDBC Driver Class: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

**This is my JDBC Request Sampler information:**

```
Query Type: Callable Statement  
Procedure: call office_hierarchy()
```

**This is the error that I get:**

```
ORA-20999: Oracle ERROR:: ORA-29478: Implicit result cannot be returned through this statement  
ORA-06512: at 'XXXX.UTILS", line 2019  
ORA-06512: at "XXXX.OFFICE_HIERARCHY", line 39
```

I purposely replaced my user with XXXX.

I'm setting up a JMeter test script, in which I call stored procedures in our Oracle database. The Oracle database is on version 12C. I use the latest version ojdbc8.jar from the Oracle website. I have also tried ojdbc6.jar and ojdbc7.jar, also from the Oracle website. My Jmeter is on 5.0 r1840935. My java version is 1.8.0_191.

I have confirmed that the database connection can be made, for a select query can be made without problems.

Implicit results (or implicit cursors) have been introduced in Oracle 12c. Has anyone run into this issue so far? Should I change something in the way that I call the stored procedure? Or is this still perhaps a driver issue? Or could it be that JMeter doesn't support this feature yet?

Comment: show your JDBC Request,also  try using Query type `Callable Statement`

Comment: Hi user7294900, thanks for your suggestion. I have updated my initial question with additional information, I hope my question is now more clear. I can unfortunately not include images as I don't have 10 reputation yet.

Comment: Try to change in Configuration the `Transaction Isolation` to `DEFAULT`

Comment: Thanks user7294900 for your input. I tried changing the transaction isolation, but in the end it turned out that the error was related to my syntax. I have posted an answer below where I explain this in more detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some digging, I found that this is not a driver issue. It was actually something else. I was using the wrong syntax to call the stored procedure.

**So my original syntax was:**

```
call _stored_procedure_()  
call office_hierarchy()
```

**However, the correct syntax is:**

```
BEGIN  
_stored_procedure_();  
END;  

BEGIN  
office_hierarchy();  
END;
```

This will resolve this issue, JMeter returns result sets without any issue now.

Thanks everyone for your help. I will accept my owner answer after 48 hours as per the site rules. Other input is always welcome of course!

Comment: You should accept your answer, so that others can trust it. Thanks for contributing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried to accept my answer, but a validation pops that I can only accept my answer tomorrow. I found in the help section that you can only accept your own answer after 48 hours.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to download [ojdbc7.jar for Oracle 12c](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/jdbc-drivers-12c-download-1958347.html) and drop it into [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath). Delete all the previous JDBC drivers and restart JMeter
2. Make sure to use `Callable Statement` as the Query Type in the [JDBC Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler

   [image]
3. You will also need to change ["Validation query" to `select 1 from dual` in the JDBC Connection Configuration](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732729-How-to-use-Different-JDBC-Drivers)

   [image]

Comment: Hi Dmitri, thanks for your suggestions. I have tried your steps but it didn't solve my problem. I have updated my initial question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are still useing 11g version of the ojdbc driver.
Check `user.classpath` property value in `JMETER_HOME/bin/user.properties` to ensure what you use properly verion of ojdbc7.jar for Oracle 12c in `JMETER_HOME/lib`

Comment: Hi Vadim, thanks for your response. I went through these steps when checking my drivers. I tried this with ojdbc6.jar, ojdbc7.jar and the new ojdbc8.jar. After some analysis I found that my syntax is wrong. I have added an answer on this page that explains the syntax mistake in detail.

Comment: @JohanK great! but accept your answer to help others find it.